# Client side code in React with statically generated site

Tags: reactjs

I am statically generating a site with React (and GatsbyJS.)

I want cases like a disclosure widget to render open when JavaScript is disabled.

I know with server side rendering you can throw an error and use `Suspense` to fallback for client side content. However, I can't figure out a similar thing for static generation.

Currently I use a context and a provider like the following.

```
const Client = createContext(false);

export const useClient = () => useContext(Client);

export const ClientProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [, startTransition] = useTransition();
  const [client, setClient] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => startTransition(() => setClient(true)), []);
  return <Client.Provider value={client}>{children}</Client.Provider>;
};
```

`ClientProvider` is then wrapped around the root of the app.

If I were to use a simpler hook like the following I would have the client state local to each component and reset every time the component is mounted and unmounted.

```
export const useClient = () => {
  const [, startTransition] = useTransition();
  const [client, setClient] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => startTransition(() => setClient(true)), []);
  return client;
};
```

This feels a little inelegant though and I was curious if there was a better way.

I also used a utility like

```
export const Client = ({children, fallback}) =>
useClient() ? <Suspense fallback={fallback}>{children}</Suspense> : fallback;
```

However, I stopped using it as much because changing the tree of nodes resets state and causes performance problems.

Comment: I suspect I might want useLayoutEffect